# Multiple formulas overlaid on a scatterplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

everyone. I have a set of data that I have called `df_train` and various regression formulas of interest. Here they are for your reference:

```
df_train <- data.frame(
  x = c(0, 0.111111, 0.222222, 0.333333, 0.444444, 0.555556, 0.666667, 0.777778, 0.888889, 1),
  y = c(0.349486, 0.830839, 1.007332, 0.971507, 0.133066, 0.166823, -0.848307, -0.445686, -0.563567, 0.261502))

forms <- c("y~1", 
           "y~x",
           "y~poly(x, 2, raw=TRUE)",
           "y~poly(x, 3, raw=TRUE)",
           "y~poly(x, 4, raw=TRUE)",
           "y~poly(x, 5, raw=TRUE)",
           "y~poly(x, 6, raw=TRUE)",
           "y~poly(x, 7, raw=TRUE)",
           "y~poly(x, 8, raw=TRUE)",
           "y~poly(x, 9, raw=TRUE)")
```

I would like to create a similar graph to the one yielded by this code, but in a more concise way.

```
df_train_exp <- df_train %>%
  add_column(., forms = forms) %>%
  expand(., x, forms) %>%
  left_join(., df_train) %>%
  select(., x, y, forms) %>%
  group_by(., forms) %>%
  arrange(., forms, x) %>%
  ungroup(.)

ggplot(df_train_exp, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE, formula = forms[1], size = 0.5) +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE, formula = forms[2], size = 0.5) +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE, formula = forms[3], size = 0.5) +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE, formula = forms[4], size = 0.5) +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE, formula = forms[5], size = 0.5) +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE, formula = forms[6], size = 0.5) +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE, formula = forms[7], size = 0.5) +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE, formula = forms[8], size = 0.5) +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE, formula = forms[9], size = 0.5) +
  theme_classic()
```

I have attempted the following but to no avail.

```
ggplot(df_train_exp, aes(x = x, y = y, color = forms)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE, formula = forms, size = 0.5) +
  theme_classic()
```

I would appreciate any help or guidance, and thanks in advance to those more R savvy than me.

Comment: Those are character values. If you want them to be actual R formulas then you may need to use as.formula.

Comment: @42- Is it necessary to convert them using `as.formula`? I tried both with and without, and didn't see any effect.

Comment: I didn't really know if conversion was necessary. The ggplot2 semantics has a lot of non-standard evaluation mechanisms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a fully reproducible solution:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(purrr)

df_train <- data.frame(x = c(0, 0.111111, 0.222222, 0.333333, 0.444444, 0.555556, 0.666667, 0.777778, 0.888889, 1),
                       y = c(0.349486, 0.830839, 1.007332, 0.971507, 0.133066, 0.166823, -0.848307, -0.445686, -0.563567, 0.261502))

forms <- c("y ~ 1", 
           "y ~ x",
           "y ~ poly(x = x, degree = 2, raw = TRUE)",
           "y ~ poly(x = x, degree = 3, raw = TRUE)",
           "y ~ poly(x = x, degree = 4, raw = TRUE)",
           "y ~ poly(x = x, degree = 5, raw = TRUE)",
           "y ~ poly(x = x, degree = 6, raw = TRUE)",
           "y ~ poly(x = x, degree = 7, raw = TRUE)",
           "y ~ poly(x = x, degree = 8, raw = TRUE)",
           "y ~ poly(x = x, degree = 9, raw = TRUE)")

ggplot(data = df_train,
       mapping = aes(x = x,
                     y = y)) +
  geom_point() +
  map(.x = forms,
      .f = ~ geom_smooth(mapping = aes(colour = paste("Model", which(x = (forms == .x)))),
                         method = "lm",
                         se = FALSE,
                         formula = .x,
                         size = 0.5)) +
  scale_colour_viridis_d(name = "legend",
                         aesthetics = "colour") +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-09-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Hope this helps.

Comment: I still haven't developed the intuition for when I need the `purrr` mapping tools. What in this problem made the mapping necessary? I still don't understand why my attempted solution didn't work. I put the data in long format, and made the formula the color variable, so exactly does my attempted solution not work?

Comment: @StatGuy45 Feel free to substitute the `map(...)` part with the corresponding `lapply(...)` call: `lapply(X = forms, FUN = function(t) geom_smooth(mapping = aes(colour = paste("Model", which(x = (forms == t)))), method = "lm", se = FALSE, formula = t, size = 0.5))`. I used `map` because it seemed to me that you're after a `tidyverse` solution.

Comment: @StatGuy45 The point is that you'll have to add the multiple layers in a `list`. Actually I came to know about this from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56990160/11117265